# Random load dates from database

Tags: php, sql

Please I need help. I need load random companies from database where `sk_popis`, `kategorie1` and who it edit is `NULL`.

```
<?php

    if ($akce=="vyber_firmu") {
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT sk_popis, kategorie1, upravil FROM firmy_popisy INNER JOIN firmy ON firmy_popisy.id = firmy.id LIMIT 1");  
        $tmpq=mysql_fetch_array($query);

        header("Location: upravafirem.php?id=$tmpq[id]");
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Thanks for tips

Answer (score 0):

Add [`ORDER BY RAND()`](http://davidwalsh.name/mysql-random) to your SQL query to return random rows.

You should note that the `mysql_*` extensions are deprecated and will be removed, you should use PDO or mysqli. See: [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli)